# Proceed to Checkout is missing with overridden Block and template file

Tags: magento2.2

Extended OOB Onepage Link Block and link.phtml to disable the button based on customer group id, the changes are working but the button is disabled for all the customers, not just for the customers that are in specified group. I cleared cache many times but still no luck. I have correct entries in checkout_cart_index.xml and I do see it working but not the way it's supposed to do. Is there anything else that needs to be done to fix this issue since it prevent checkout for all the customers?

Answer (score 0):

Found out hard way that it was a simple typo in the Block class name, I was using wrong Session class, where required method wasn't available. Took sometime to find this out and but it's working now. Please make sure that vendor/module, and/or other names are correct with case, otherwise it's hard to debug since we don't get meaningful errors unlike Java. I couldn't enable developer mode due to other issues which also complicated the problem.